# Creating Projects Dynamically

Tags: c#

I want create dynamically projects in my solution

**C# Code**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string projectPath = @"C:\Users\lucas_000\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\ModelingProject1\ModelingProject1\ModelingProject1.modelproj";
            using (IModelingProjectReader projectReader = ModelingProject.LoadReadOnly(projectPath))
            {
               IModelStore store = projectReader.Store;
               foreach (IClass umlClass in store.AllInstances<IClass>())
               {
                   try
                   {
                       Engine engine = new Engine();                       
                       //engine.BinPath = RuntimeEnvironment.GetRuntimeDirectory();
                       Project project = engine.CreateNewProject();

                       project.AddNewImport(@"$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets", null);

                       BuildPropertyGroup props = project.AddNewPropertyGroup(false);
                       props.AddNewProperty("AssemblyName", "myassembly");
                       props.AddNewProperty("OutputType", "Library");

                       BuildItemGroup items = project.AddNewItemGroup();
                       items.AddNewItem("Reference", "Some.Assembly");
                       items.AddNewItem("Compile", "somefile.cs");

                       project.Save("myproject.csproj");
                   }
                   catch (Exception e2)
                   {
                   }
               }
            }
        }
```

**Problem**

When will Save the project, occurs the `UnauthorizedAccessException` in a folder that I don't want Save this new project there.

How can I create this project in my current Solution in Visual Studio 2010 ?

**UPDATE**

The Line `project.Save("myproject.csproj")` tries to save in `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DevServer\10.0\myproject.csproj`

All my solution are in `C:\Users\lucas_000\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects`

Comment: Could it be of this line: using (IModelingProjectReader projectReader = ModelingProject.LoadReadOnly(projectPath))... You appear to be loading the project 'ReadOnly'.

Comment: This line I'm loading an UML model, and the line in `project.Save()` tries to save the new project in `CommonFiles` folder, this is strange because all my `Solution` are saved in the VisualStudio's folder, in my `Documents` folder. I updated my question with more information

Comment: Always avoid relying on the current directory being set right, it certainly won't be in VS.  Specify the *full path*, c:\foo\bar\baz.txt, not just baz.txt.  Just like you did for *projectPath*.

Comment: Are you attempting to do this from within VS or from another exe? If you are doing this in VS I would highly recommend using the `DTE` instead of your current approach. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/envdte.dte.aspx)